# how to use an open file for reuse it in severals functions?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in python and not completely bilingual, so I hope you understand me. I'm trying to develop a code where anyone can open a file, in order to display its contents in a graph matplotlib, to do this using a function called `read_file()` with which I get the data and insert a `Listbox` without any problems. I accomplished the functionality but my concern arises when I want to call the information contained in the file from another function called `show_graph()`, in this part I require use the loaded file  (in the `read_file()` function), the only way to achieve this is by adding:

```
f = open(‘example1.las')

log = LASReader(f, null_subs=np.nan)
```

with which I can plot, but not practical for me, in other words how to use an open file for reuse it in severals functions?

Someone could give me their support to solve this please?

Here is the complete code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from las import LASReader
from pprint import pprint
import tkFileDialog
import matplotlib, sys
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x700+10+10")

def read_file():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    f = open(filename)
    log = LASReader(f, null_subs=np.nan)

    for curve in log.curves.names:
    parent.insert(END,curve)

def add_name():
    it = parent.get(ACTIVE)
    child.insert(END, it)

def show_graph():
    child = Listbox(root, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
    try:
        s = child.selection_get()
        if s == "GR":
            print 'selected:', s            
            f = open('example1.las')
            log = LASReader(f, null_subs=np.nan)


            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 7.5))

            plt.plot(log.data['GR'], log.data['DEPT'])
            plt.ylabel(log.curves.DEPT.descr + " (%s)" % log.curves.DEPT.units)
            plt.xlabel(log.curves.GR.descr + " (%s)" % log.curves.GR.units)
            plt.ylim(log.stop, log.start)
            plt.title(log.well.WELL.data + ', ' + log.well.DATE.data)
            plt.grid()
            dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
            dataPlot.show()
            dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,
                sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=380, pady=52)

        elif s == "NPHI":
            print 'selected:', s
            f = open('Shamar-1.las')
            log = LASReader(f, null_subs=np.nan) 


            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 7.5))

            plt.plot(log.data['NPHI'], log.data['DEPT'])
            plt.ylabel(log.curves.DEPT.descr + " (%s)" % log.curves.DEPT.units)
            plt.xlabel(log.curves.NPHI.descr + " (%s)" % log.curves.NPHI.units)
            plt.ylim(log.stop, log.start)
            plt.title(log.well.WELL.data + ', ' + log.well.DATE.data)
            plt.grid()
            dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
            dataPlot.show()
            dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,
                sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=380, pady=52)

        elif s == "DPHI":
            print 'selected:', s
            f = open('Shamar-1.las')
            log = LASReader(f, null_subs=np.nan) 


            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 7.5))

            plt.plot(log.data['DPHI'], log.data['DEPT'])
            plt.ylabel(log.curves.DEPT.descr + " (%s)" % log.curves.DEPT.units)
            plt.xlabel(log.curves.DPHI.descr + " (%s)" % log.curves.DPHI.units)
            plt.ylim(log.stop, log.start)
            plt.title(log.well.WELL.data + ', ' + log.well.DATE.data)
            plt.grid()
            dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
            dataPlot.show()
            dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,
                sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=380, pady=52)

    except:
        print 'no selection'

def remove_name():
    child.delete(ACTIVE)

def btnClick():
        pass

e = Entry(root)
e.pack(padx=5)
b = Button(root, text="OK", command=btnClick)
b.pack(pady=5)

# create the canvas, size in pixels
canvas = Canvas(width = 490, height = 600, bg = 'grey')
# pack the canvas into a frame/form
canvas.place(x=340, y=50)

etiqueta = Label(root, text='Nemonics:')
etiqueta.place(x=10, y=30)

parent = Listbox(root)

root.title("Viewer")

parent.place(x=5, y=50)

selec_button = Button(root, text='Graph',
                    command=show_graph)
selec_button.place(x=340, y=20)

remove_button = Button(root, text='<<delete',
                    command=remove_name)
remove_button.place(x=138, y=150)

add_button = Button(root, text='Add>>',
                    command=add_name)
add_button.place(x=138, y=75)


child = Listbox(root)
child.place(x=210, y=50)

butt = Button(root, text="load file", command=read_file)
butt.place(x=10, y=5)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"but not practical for me"* - why not? Passing around the handle of an open file is likely to lead to more confusion.

Comment: can your copy the file to a temp file, use it and then delete it?

Comment: you could load the file and pass a `io.StringIO` object which has almost the same interface as actual file handles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable to keep it, declaring it as global before the variable name (f in your case). However, I don't recommend it if you are modifying the file.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the lasreader you use?
https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/LASReader.html

Then you should not need to give it a file handle. Just give the filename an this should do the trick. The reader will close the file after parsing.

```
def read_file():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    log = LASReader(filename, null_subs=np.nan)
```

If you have read the contents of a file usually you can close it afterwards:

```
f = open(filename)
log = LASReader(f, null_subs=np.nan)
f.close()
```

or use with which closes the file for you automatically

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    log = LASReader(f, null_subs=np.nan)
```